# Adding underline to part of the paragraph on the same line docx4j

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

```
Name: __John_____________________________
Age:  __30_______________________________
```

Im trying to achieve the above in docx. I am using docx4j. I would want the underline to also be nicely formatted to the right

Main code below

```
paragraph = getParagraph(factory, "Name: John", "", true);
mainDocumentPart.getContent().add(paragraph);
```

Method below

```
private P getParagraph(ObjectFactory factory, String content, String right, boolean underline) {
        P paragraph = factory.createP();
        Text text = factory.createText();
        text.setValue(content);

        R run = factory.createR();
        run.getContent().add(text);
        if (underline) {
            U u = factory.createU();
            u.setVal(UnderlineEnumeration.SINGLE);
            RPr rpr = factory.createRPr();
            rpr.setU(u);
            rpr.setB(new BooleanDefaultTrue());
            run.setRPr(rpr);
        }

        paragraph.getContent().add(run);

        return paragraph;
    }
```

How can i achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to underline just the word "John", you'd need to put it in a separate run. For example:

```
    <w:p>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>Name: __</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:u w:val="single"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>John</w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
            <w:t>_____________________________</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```